# Passthrough function in parameters not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of announcements, each announcement shows up in a snackbar and has some text and a button:

```js
// announcements.services.ts
notificationConfig: {
    buttons: [
        {
            text: this.translateService.instant(_('Go to Insights dashboard')),
            action: () => {
                this.router.navigate(['/dm/statistics/insights']);
                this.dismissAnnouncement(AnnouncementName.INSIGHTS_DASHBOARD);
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

```html
// toast-notification.html
<div *ngFor="let button of buttons" class="buttonWrapper">
    <app-button (click)="callButtonAction(button.action)">{{ button.text | translate }}</app-button>
</div>
```

```js
// toast-notification.component.ts 
close() {
    console.log(2);
    this.onClose.emit();
}

callButtonAction(action: (closeHandler: CloseHandler) => void) {
    console.log(1);
    action(() => this.close());
}
```

When I click the button in the snackbar I do the see the `console.log(1)` from the `callButtonAction()` but the `this.close()` is not being fired.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not using the handler given to `action` in `action(() => this.close())`.

Try this:

```
notificationConfig: {
    buttons: [
        {
            text: this.translateService.instant(_('Go to Insights dashboard')),
            action: (callback) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/dm/statistics/insights']);
                this.dismissAnnouncement(AnnouncementName.INSIGHTS_DASHBOARD);
                callback()
            },
        },
    ],
},
```